# Incorrect argument label in call when using ObjectMapper

Tags: swift, swift3

I am using [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) to convert model objects (classes and structs) to and from JSON.

When I try to create an instance like this `let person = Person(username: "name", age: 24)`, I get errors like:

> incorrect argument label in call
>
> and extra argument in call

I believe its to do with the way struct is being initialised, how can I fix this ?

```
import ObjectMapper

func viewDidLoad(){
  super.viewDidLoad()

  let person = Person(username: "name", age: 24)
}


struct Person: Mappable {
  var username: String?
  var age: Int?

  init?(map: Map) {    //To conform to Mappable class of ObjectMapper
    
  }

  // Mappable
  mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
    username    <- map["username"]
    age         <- map["age"]
    
  }

}
```

Comment: I know nothing about that library or its `Map` class but your `Person` class's `init` method takes one parameter named `map`, not two named `username` and `age`.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to use the synthetised memberwised initializer of `Person`. However, since you explicitly defined another initializer, the compiler didn't synthetise the memberwise initializer, you'll need to do that manually.

Comment: The error is silenced when I add an extra initialiser `init(username: String, age: Int){ }` I believe this is ok ?

Comment: @user44776 Is your `definition` okay alright with having a `nil` name and age? If so, then sure, it's fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to use the synthetised memberwised initializer of Person. However, since you explicitly defined another initializer, the compiler didn't synthetise the memberwise initializer, you'll need to do that manually.

```
struct Person: Mappable {
    var userName: String?
    var age: Int?

    init(userName:String? = nil, age:Int? = nil){
        self.userName = userName
        self.age = age
    }

    init?(map: Map) {    //To conform to Mappable class of ObjectMapper

    }

    // Mappable
    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
        username    <- map["username"]
        age         <- map["age"]

    }
}
```

You can call the initializer using only a username, only an age or both due to the default values.

```
let person = Person(userName: "name", age: 24)
let nameless = Person(age: 20)
let ageless = Person(userName: "name")
```

This initializer is only an example, in your real application I guess you actually want at least `userName` to have a non-nil value, so you should change the declaration to be non-optional and change the initializer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create instance like below :

If you want to use default `init` for the `Mappable` class

```
let jsonString = "{\"username\":\"username\",\"age\":20}"
let person = Person(JSONString: jsonString) // here you have to send json string as parameter
print(person?.username) // Outputs : Optional("username")
print(person?.age) // Outputs : Optional(20)
```